# Spring Social Facebook - publish/post API details

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I have been looking into Spring Social Facebook's **publish(objectId, connectionName, data)** [API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/FacebookTemplate.html#publish%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap%29), but am not sure of the usage of this API (sadly, due to lack of javadocs!). Can someone point me to a comprehensive sample usage of the API, please?

What I am looking to do is publish a story on a user's wall, similar to the below snapshot:

[image]

How should the **publish() API** be used to do the same? Any help is highly appreciated!

Also, I need my post to have additional actions (apart from Like, Comment).

Comment: Do want this only through spring social?? I have solution through Spring Rest(Using RestTemplete or Httpclient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I could finally figure out:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.set("link", linkUrlString);
map.set("name", "Link Heading");
map.set("caption", "Link Caption");
map.set("description", "Loooooo....ng description here");
map.set("message", "hello world");

// THE BELOW LINES ARE THE CRITICAL PART I WAS LOOKING AT!
map.set("picture", "http://www.imageRepo.com/resources/test.png"); // the image on the left
map.set("actions", "{'name':'myAction', 'link':'http://www.bla.com/action'}"); // custom actions as JSON string

publish(userIdToPostTo, "feed", map);
```

Comment: I did the same,all are working but image is not showing,img src is correct including my image url but its not loading,do i need something else?

Answer (score 6):

[The link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/FacebookTemplate.html#publish%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap%29) given by you already having a lot documentation for method.

Find one example with flow of `publish(objectId, connectionName, data)`  [here](http://git.springsource.org/~felipera/spring-social/feliperas-spring-social/commit/1e26a8c4fdec4cb8a089bed5127e611ea68673fd)

Also see many examples for at [github-SpringSource](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-facebook/blob/master/spring-social-facebook/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/impl/FeedTemplate.java) for additional actions including `publish(objectId, connectionName, data)`.

Update:

You might get some help from this method:

```
public void postToWall(String message, FacebookLink link) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.set("link", link.getLink());
    map.set("name", link.getName());
    map.set("caption", link.getCaption());
    map.set("description", link.getDescription());
    map.set("message", message);
    publish(CURRENT_USER, FEED, map);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that Spring's javadoc link is of much use in this case. I believe there needs more documentation on what goes into the parameters of the API. Also, the references given by you are trivial ones. What I am looking for is , for example, how to setup  the *data* parameter (i.e., what values to add to the map), so as to have custom actions on the post.

Comment: I use code like Somnath's, plus I set these additional key/value pairs in the map:
`map.set("message", message); // the "It's hard to imagine..." part for you` and `map.set("picture", linkPictureURL); // the icon URL`
Also, in case it wasn't clear, the `FEED` constant should have a value of `"feed"`.

Comment: this works and is close to what I was looking for, but not exactly.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk : I use this code and I do see the post on my page but it just see what I put in the message field other link attributes do not post. Any suggestion what could be wrong?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I found the reason for that behaviour. Actually I was on development environment and was trying to make a post with link with a localhost url. I had the link point to a published environment and it worked OK. Thanks for your anser. it works like a charm though.

Answer (score 0):

Like above answer but I use post for my solution. See this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map1.set("link", "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006216492034");
        map1.set("name", "Project Test Post to Group");
        map1.set("caption", "Please ignore this Post");
        map1.set("description", "YOLO here is my discription, Please ignore this post");
facebook.post("userId or GroupID", "feed", map);
```

Comment: I update my answer that your facebook app need to disable Stream post URL security.
Your app/Settings/Migrations/Disable Stream post URL security